# angular, getting formarray controls inside template page error

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular-directive

I'm trying to make a nested formarrays example .

at somepoint I need to get the controls of the form array inside my html page in the forloop like this:

```
<!--this is the outer loop-->
<div *ngFor="let comp of companiesFormArr.controls; let i=index">

    <!--inner loop-->
    <div *ngFor="let project of comp.get('projects')['controls']; let j=index">

    </div>

</div>
```

on other examples when I search > using this line of code won't coz any error:

```
comp.get('projects')['controls']
```

I tried to avoid using it and using the get method in the typescript file like this:

```
get namedControd(){
 return (this.namedForm.get('namedArray') as FormArray).controls;
}
```

and it works fine for the outer loop but when I try to do the same for the inner loop I can't do the same behavior > so > I will make a function in the typescript file and pass it the comp object to return the controls like this:

```
  getSomeControls(someFormArray: any){
    return (<FormArray>someFormArray.get('secondNamedArray')).controls;
  }
```

and then use the above function inside the inner for loop , and this is making some other issues .

the error which I'm getting when I use :

```
comp.get('something').controls
```

or :

```
comp.get('something')['controls']
```

inside the template html is that the comp Object is possibly 'null'

is there a way to avoid this error rather than check the object comp using the *ngIf because I already try it but the error is still the same. ???

any help will be appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is Typescript saying that it can't be sure that the result of the .get() function actually returns an item. It can be a pain in the ass, but there are some ways to deal with this.

One is use an exclamation mark:
`comp.get('something')!.controls` this tells TS to ignore the warning, and that you are certain it will definitely return something. Note that if it doesn't, TS will not be there to help you out, so only use it if you're sure that the function will indeed return something.

TS operators *do not work in templates* however. You could get around casting the returned value in the get function:

```
get = () => {
  return something as SomeType;
}
```

where sometype is the type or interface of whatever you're returning. Also here you should mind that you're telling TS to consider the value as being of that type, even if in reality it's not.

Comment: @MohammedDarwish as an additional note, be careful with nested for loops and calling functions within them. With large collections, this might negatively impact the page's performance. Splitting the code up into separate components might help here.

Comment: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'. is what I'm getting when I use this comp.get('something')!.controls

Comment: I don't know what the code of that method is, but presumably you're using or casting as the wrong type...